# Git not adding the deleted file after uncommiting

Tags: git

I have deleted a file, committed and pushed to my branch. And later, I have uncommitted using git reset --hard Head~1.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout to the branch before you did your changes, get a copy of that file and commit again to the branch where you committed the deleted file.

Answer (score 0):

What you just needed to do is, `git reset --SOFT Head~1.` (`SOFT` instead of `HARD`) so as to get to that stage before the commit and the deleted file would have been in staging stage.